# Stability of successive minima with respect to the metric on the space of lattices

Tags: lattices, diophantine-approximation, geometry-of-numbers

Let $\mathcal L$ be the space of unimodular (covolume one) lattices in $\mathbb R^d$. The **$i$-th successive minimum** of $L\in \mathcal L$, denoted $\lambda_i(L)$ is the infimum of the radii of the balls containing $i$-linearly independent vectors in $L$.

Recall that the space of unimodular lattices can be identified with $G/\Gamma$ where $G=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $\Gamma=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$. There is a $G$-invariant (Riemannian) metric $\text{dist}$ on $G/\Gamma$.

I wonder if we have any inequality like

$$ |\lambda_i(g\mathbb Z^d)- \lambda_i(h\mathbb Z^d)| \le C_d \text{dist}(g\Gamma, h\Gamma), \forall g,h \in G, \forall i$$

or like

$$ |\log \lambda_i(g\mathbb Z^d)- \log \lambda_i(h\mathbb Z^d)| \le C_d \text{dist}(g\Gamma, h\Gamma), \forall g,h \in G, \forall i$$

for some $C_d>0$ that only depends on the dimension $d$. (Or RHS can be replaced by a nonlinear function of $\text{dist}(g\Gamma, h\Gamma)$)

Comment: I'm only really familiar with the lattices side of things, but there has been some work bounding how the voronoi cell of a lattice behaves under small deformations, see [claim 3.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05979.pdf). I don't know how to extract any information about $\lambda_i$ out of this, but it seems plausibly of interest anyway.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, Voronoi cells certainly give information about $\lambda_1$  at least.